# How to loop through functions by name in P5js / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, p5.js

I'm working on a basic P5 program that requires up to ten input boxes.

So I need to first create the button instances, using e.g.

```
  factor1Input = createInput(""); // create DOM element for input field
  factor1Input.position(leftMargin, topMargin + 50); // place button on screen
  factor1Input.changed(this.factor1update); // call function when value changes
  factor1Button = createButton('Update Factor'); // create DOM element for button
  factor1Button.position(100, 100); // position button
```

Then toggle their visibility using e.g.

```
    factor1Input.show(); // toggle display on
    factor1Button.show();

    factor1Input.hide(); // or toggle it off 
    factor1Button.hide();
```

But because I'll have up to 10, this will require a ton of repetitive code.

So I want to create a loop that goes something like (e.g. just for the show function);

```
    for (let i = 1; i < factorCount; i++){
      let fci = "factor" + i + "Input"; 
      let fcb = "factor" + i + "Button"; 

      fci.show(); 
      fcb.show(); 
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fci.show is not a function
```

Which suggests some kind of type mismatch, i.e. I can't seem to just compile a string, and have this recognized as the JavaScript function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is called "projection" and should be avoided at all costs. You should instead use a class, create instances and keep references to them in an array. What are these factors? What's toggling the visibility?

Answer (score 1):

fci will be a string so the String class will not have a method show, You will get an exception. Instead

You can write in this way

```
var factorObject = {
  factor1Input:createInput("")
}
factorObject['factor1Input'].position(leftMargin, topMargin + 50);
```

For show

```
factorObject['factor1Input'].show();
```

Here in the loop

```
 for (let i = 1; i < factorCount; i++){
      let fci = "factor" + i + "Input"; 
      factorObject[fci].show(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you create a string and try to call it like a variable with the same name

```
let fci = "factor" + i + "Input"; 
fci.show(); // fci is just a string 'factor1Input', has nothing in common with factor1Input variable
```

You should use arrays [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and instead of keeping input number (e.g. index) inside a name, let it be the index of an item in the array

```
const factorCount = 10
const inputs = []
const buttons = []

// example of creating inputs and buttons in a loop, you can create them manually if you want,
// but don't forget to .push them to respective array

for (let i = 1; i < factorCount; i++){
  const input = createInput("");
  input.position(leftMargin, topMargin + 50 * i); // using index to calculate top margin
  input.changed((value) => this.factorUpdate(i, value)); // notice the change here
  inputs.push(input)
  const button = createButton('Update Factor');
  button.position(100, 100 + 50 * i); // also using index to calculate top margin
  buttons.push(button)
}


function showInput(index) {
  inputs[index].show()
  buttons[index].show()
}

function hideInput(index) {
  inputs[index].hide()
  buttons[index].hide()
}

showInput(3) // shows 3rd input and button
hideInput(4) // hides 4th input and button
```

Notice also how I changed your `this.factor1update` method call. The same way you don't want to have 10 separate variables for 10 elements, you don't want to have 10 methods to handle changes on those 10 elements (what if there was 10000 elements?). Instead, create one method `factorUpdate` that will receive item index and the value that was changed and use that to handle the input change

---

added:

```
for (let i = 0; i < factorCount; i++){ // changed 1 to 0 here, it was a typo
  const input = createInput("");
  input.position(leftMargin, topMargin + 50 * i);
  input.changed(() => factorUpdate(i)); // we call factorUpdate with index of an element
  inputs.push(input)
  const button = createButton('Update Factor');
  button.position(185, topMargin + 50 * i);
  buttons.push(button)
}

function factorUpdate(i, event){
  // argument i is now an index of unfocused input
  console.log("input index: " + i + ", value: " + inputs[i].value());
}
```

Note also how `input.changed()` works: you edit the input, then you click somewhere else on the page to unfocus it, and that's when this event is triggered. With that in mind, buttons here don't actually do anything as there are no click listeners assigned to them

Comment: Actually, Max, it's close, but I'm running into some other issues with this code. Can you take a look? https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/07YcpXUzS You'll see a warning in line 18. And then it looks like I'm doing something wrong with capturing the array element value after updating (e.g.) the first input field.

Comment: that is just a warning about confusing semantics, but that is totally fine. There is another problem however, in my example I passed specific params to `factorUpdate` function so that you can use them to know which input was updated, but in your code you don't use them, so regardless of what event was updated,  the same `factorUpdate` will always run and log the first input. Edited my answer with simplified example

Comment: Thanks Max, this is now working as expected. It doesn't look like so many Update buttons are actually needed, https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/07YcpXUzS

Comment: hi Max, quick question, is there a way to rewrite the lamda function not as a lamda function? Also, for the line `function factorUpdate(i, event){` the code is working without the second "event" parameter. Is that param necessary?

Comment: @ChrisAmato yes you can use classic function as well `function() { factorUpdate(i) }` and no, `event` param is not necessary if you are not using it